# Import Opera bookmarks to Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, opera, bookmarks

How to import Opera bookmarks into Chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Type "opera://bookmarks" in your Opera browser. This will list all the bookmarks saved under Opera browser
2. After step 1, you will see an "Import/Export" option at the bottom left of the Opera browser screen
3. Select "Export Bookmarks" and save it to an HTML file
4. In your Chrome browser, go to the 3 vertical dots at the top right of the Chrome browser screen, then go to "Settings" and search for "Import bookmarks and settings"
5. In "Import bookmarks and settings" select "Bookmarks HTML File" then select "Choose File" and select the HTML file you saved in Step 3, and then finally select "Done"
6. In Chrome go to the 3 vertical dots at the top right of the Chrome browser screen then select "Bookmarks" then select the "Imported" folder

Comment: Just an addition, if you want to move that bookmarks from Imported folder to root folder, right click to bookmark bar, select "bookmark manager", then select the bookmarks you want to move and copy them to the root folder.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this follows steps:

1. Type `opera://bookmarks` in you Opera browser. This will list all the bookmarks saved under Opera browser.
2. After step 1, you will see `Import/Export` option in Left bottom screen of Opera browser.
3. Select `Export Bookmarks` and save it to a html file
4. In Chrome browser, goto Settings option and search for `Import bookmarks and settings`;
5. Chrome -> Select `Bookmarks HTML file` option -> Choose File (select the saved HTML file in Step 3);
6. The imported bookmarks in Chrome will be visible under `Imported->Bookmarks bar`